# Gulp-sass not finding variable in included files(s)?

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have a _variables.scss file where a map is declared:

```
$chord1: (
  color1: rgb(0, 155, 223), 
  color2: rgb(114, 191, 68), 
  color3: rgb(207, 9, 137), 
  color4: rgb(62, 83, 164)
);

$chord: $chord1;
```

I have a second file. `_globals.scss` where I reference this:

```
.myClass { color: map-get($chord, color1); }
```

I have a the main scss file as app.scss, which @imports  them:

```
@import 'colors';
@import 'globals';
```

However, gulp-sass throws an error `Error: invalid top-level expression` based on that map-get.

I was using gulp-ruby-sass on one project and it worked.  However, in this project we are using gulp-sass 1.1.0.  My gulp task is:

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
   return gulp.src('./app/assets/sass/app.scss')
   .pipe(plumber())
   .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/assets/css'))
   .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Does this sort of thing just not work in gulp-sass?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Half guess: Imports work fine but node-sass doesn't support maps that came with [Sass 3.3](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/master/doc-src/SASS_CHANGELOG.md#330-7-march-2014).

https://github.com/sass/node-sass#reporting-sass-compilation-and-syntax-issues

> The libsass library is not currently at feature parity with the 3.2 Ruby Gem that most Sass users will use, and has little-to-no support for 3.3 syntax. While we try our best to maintain feature parity with libsass, we can not enable features that have not been implemented in libsass yet.

Comment: Could be.  I removed my maps and it compiles.